# compiling static library issue

Tags: xcode

I'm creating a static library with some frameworks and a third part static library.
To avoid the conflicting problem， how to manage the static library when I release the library ? 
And  if my library users  has import the same frameworks, when I compiling the  static library, should I select the link binary?

Comment: I get some answer from google. The statndard framesworks will add a reference to my library, and between the library and user's app don't have the duplicate problem. But if custom library maybe has the problem. And  is there some solution?

Comment: if they(client app) don't use  cocoapods,  is there other solution ?